# cannot login into postgres Docker database using pgadmin portal

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I am using Docker to create a postgres database and `pgadmin-portal`.

In my `docker-compose.yaml` I am setting the `POSTGRES_USER` to be 'root' with a `password` of 'password'.

`docker-compose.yaml` (I have left the frontend and backend in but I don't think they're particularly relevant)

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./apps/server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./apps/server:/svr/app
      - "./scripts/wait.sh:/wait.sh"
      - /svr/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - gh-network
    ports:
      - "${BACKEND_PORT}:${BACKEND_PORT}"
    depends_on:
      - gh-pg-db
    links:
      - gh-pg-db
  gh-pg-db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: gh-pg-db
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - gh-network
  pgadmin-portal:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    container_name: pgadmin-portal
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT}:80"
    depends_on:
      - gh-pg-db
    networks:
      - gh-network
volumes:
  pgdata:
  pgadmin:

networks:
  gh-network:
    driver: bridge
```

However in PGAdmin when I try to connect to the DB with the following details (below) I get this error (below some more):

Details

```
    host/name address:   gh-pg-db
    port:                5432
    username:            root
    password:            password
```

Error

```
Unable to connect to server:
connection to server at "gh-pg-db" (172.20.0.2), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
```

When I access the terminal for the postgres server (gh-pg-db) in Docker Desktop and run the `\l` command I get this list(below) and the `Owner` is always `postgres` so I can only assume that the `PG_USER` line in the doccker-composer.yaml is not working as the user should be `root` and not `postgres`.

```
                                List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 gh-pg-db  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Specifically, my question is, am I setting the `PG_USER` for the `pgadmin-portal` correctly?

Daniel.

Comment: The default user in Postgres is `postgres`, not `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `POSTGRES_*` variables are only used when initializing a database. If you have an existing database in your `pgdata` volume, then the environment variables have no effect and you need to use the users and passwords that are defined in the database already.

From the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) of the image:

> Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you
> start the container with a data directory that is empty; any
> pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

Comment: Hi, I don't believe I have an existing database in my `pgdata`. But just in case, how would I check if I did? Also I have previously had a postgres database installed with Docker in a completely different local project and that db was in a different volume; `database-data` to be exact. Could that cause an issue?

Comment: You can delete the volume by doing `docker volume ls`. It'll be called something like `<your directory name>_pgdata`. Then delete it using `docker volume rm <volume name>`. When you bring up the container next time, there won't be a database and your environment variables will be used.

Comment: ANSWER HERE. Deleting the volume(and container) as mentioned above by Hans Killian solved the issue. See above comment for reason why. Thank you Hans.